# How to change the layout of the default archive page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I manage the website www.frijolichtreclame.nl and I've been working on making the URLs of the portfolio page and the projects beneath it the same for SEO purposes:

.nl/projects as the page where everything is combined, .nl/projects/project-name for each specific project.

But the layout on the .nl/projects page is not what I want it to be. Now I want to change that, but the default WordPress formatting always overrules my own wishes. Is there a way to change the layout to whatever I want? The website is made using Divi, but the Divi developers say these changes cannot be done.

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: you can create divi child theme. then you can change your layout as per your requirement.

Comment: Still, the main formatting by WordPress will override my custom layout. I've been looking at other ways to change the page.php to what I want and those solutions also won't work. Is there any other way?